# Resolve intersection between two Arcs in one direction

Tags: geometry

I have two Arcs that intersect each other.

One Arc should be translated (Arc B) while the other must stay fixed in place (Arc A).
How can I find the **minimum** vector that solves the intersection of Arc B in one specific direction?

In my case, for example, I can move Arc B only upwards (+Y).

Is there a mathematical function that works for every possible case (eg. same / opposite orientation, A above / below B, etc...)?

[image: The Problem]

Thanks.

PS: Sorry, I am not an expert in mathematics...

PPS: The desired result
[image: The desired result]

Comment: What do you mean by"vector that solves the intersection"?

Comment: And even experts post questions here, so no need to feel guilty.

Comment: @Qwerty For example v(0, +15). In this case Arc B should move up by 15 units in Y to not intersect anymore with Arc A.

Comment: Well moving up is not the only solution.It could move sideways or any other direction to a certain distance to stop being intersected by Arc A

Comment: @Qwerty In my case, though, I only need one specific direction (eg. up).

Comment: You should specify clearly that " I can move only upwards" in you question

Comment: @Qwerty fixed, thanks :)

Comment: Do you have coordinates of every point of each arc?

Comment: @Qwerty Yes, I have center, start / end point, start / end angles and more of each arc.

Answer (score 0):

Find the max value of the y coordinates of Arc A. Keep increasing all Y coordinates of Arc B until the minimum Y value of Arc B exceeds The max y value of Arc A.

If your A is above B then put min in place of max and vice versa..

Comment: That wouldn't work when Arc B is flipped upside down though...
http://i.imgur.com/H94pDOQ.png

Comment: @TesX this will work.. Upvote if you like my answer

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate x from equations of these two circles.

$$ ( x- H)^2 + ( y- K)^2 = R_A^2; \, ( x- h)^2 + ( y- k)^2 = R_B^2; \, $$

Equate the discrimnant of obtained quadratic equation in $y$ to zero.

You will get $K$ in terms of $ h,k, R_A, H, R_B $

Can you take it up further? If not I could hint further.

Comment: I'm sorry but how can I eliminate x from those equations? -.-